# Angular 1.5 service unknown provider is killing me

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, typescript

So I'm working on an Angular 1.5 project with Typescript and it seems whatever I do, I can't get my own services to load. I can't see where I'm going wrong, it's probably something VERY stupid!

**EDIT**

The error is this:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: configLoaderServiceProvider <- configLoaderService <- MapController

My controller:

```
namespace app {
'use strict';
class MapController {

    // @ngInject
    constructor(private $log: angular.ILogService, configLoaderService) {
        $log.debug('MapController initialized');
        //code removed for brevity
    }
}

angular.module('app').controller('MapController', MapController);
}
```

My service:

```
namespace app {
'use strict';

export interface IConfigLoaderService {
    loadConfigFile(): any;
}

class configLoaderService implements IConfigLoaderService {
    private $http: angular.IHttpService;

    constructor($http: angular.IHttpService) {
        this.$http = $http;
    }

    loadConfigFile(): any {
        return this.$http.get('app/config/layers.json');
    }
}

angular.module('app.services')
    .service('configLoaderService', configLoaderService);

}
```

The setup for the module:

```
namespace app {
'use strict';

angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngMaterial',
    'app.controllers',
    'app.filters',
    'app.services',
    'app.directives',
    'app.routes',
    'app.config'
]);

angular.module('app.routes', []);
angular.module('app.factories', []);
angular.module('app.controllers', []);
angular.module('app.filters', []);
angular.module('app.services', []);
angular.module('app.directives', []);
angular.module('app.config', []);
angular.module('app.providers', []);
}
```

Comment: better export your service classes if you want to use them :)

Comment: So what provider is unknown?

Comment: @AranS tried it, didn't work :(

Comment: Could jo create a JSbin or something with your code so we can play with it to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys, I was REALLY dumb, there was an other service already defined by my coworker, but it recreated the app.services module instead of adding to it at that point!

So remember:

> ALWAYS CHECK ALL YOUR SERVICES!!!